# qtcreator can't find QT quick on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I would like to develop a Qt Quick application on my Ubuntu 18.04.03 machine. I am going the route of installing Qt through the Ubuntu distribution. I first install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default   # Installs Qt 5.9.5
sudo apt install qtcreator         # Version 4.5.2
```

Now I'm not sure what to install for Qt Quick, so I install these:

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls
sudo apt install qtquickcontrols2-5-dev
```

I run qtcreator, select New Project -> Qt Quick application, fill out requested information in the wizard. But after clicking "Finish" I'm presented with this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick
```

Why can't qtcreator find QT quick? Do I need to install additional packages? I am developing in C++ for desktop.

apt -cache search qtquick yields 40+ results, some of the more plausible ones being:

```
qml-module-qtquick-controls2 - Qt 5 Qt Quick Controls 2 QML module
qml-module-qtquick-dialogs - Qt 5 Dialogs QML module
qml-module-qtquick-extras - Qt 5 Quick Extras QML module
qml-module-qtquick-layouts - Qt 5 Quick Layouts QML module
qml-module-qtquick-localstorage - Qt 5 localstorage QML module
qml-module-qtquick-particles2 - Qt 5 particles 2 QML module
qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets - Qt 5 Private Widgets QML module
qml-module-qtquick-scene2d - Qt 5 Quick Scene 2D QML module
qml-module-qtquick-scene3d - Qt 5 Quick Scene 3D QML module
qml-module-qtquick-templates2 - Qt 5 Qt Quick Templates 2 QML module
qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard - Qt virtual keyboard - QML module
qml-module-qtquick-window2 - Qt 5 window 2 QML module
qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel - Qt 5 xmllistmodel QML module
qml-module-qtquick2 - Qt 5 Qt Quick 2 QML module
qtdeclarative4-kqtquickcharts-1 - QtQuick plugin to render interactive charts
qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin - transitional dummy package Qt 5 Qt Quick 2 QML module
qtdeclarative5-u1db1.0 - Qt5 binding for U1DB - QtQuick2 QML plugin
qtquickcontrols2-5-dev - Qt 5 Quick Controls 2 development files
qtquickcontrols2-5-doc - Qt 5 Quick Controls 2 documentation
qtquickcontrols2-5-doc-html - Qt 5 Quick Controls 2 HTML documentation
qtquickcontrols2-5-examples - Qt 5 Qt Quick Templates 2 examples
qtquickcontrols5-doc - Qt 5 Quick Controls documentation
qtquickcontrols5-doc-html - Qt 5 Quick Controls HTML documentation
qtquickcontrols5-examples - Qt 5 Quick Controls examples
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of  `àpt-cache search qtquick`?

Comment: If it doesn't fit in the comments then **add** it in your question.

Comment: Thanks! Added list to my original question.

Comment: qml-module-qtquick2 is already the newest version (5.9.5-0ubuntu1.1).

Comment: mmmm, Okay, then install qtdeclarative5-dev. See https://askubuntu.com/a/577334

Comment: WOW - yes, now qtcreator finds QT quick after adding qtdeclarative5-dev - I would NEVER have guessed from the package name. THANKS, good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem I bumped into recently; Qt Quick is indeed part of a different package. Just run:

```
sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

And after that you should be able to use Qt Quick without even having to restart Qt Creator.

Comment: How is this package called for Qt6?